# Removing null value rows from table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reporting, expression

I have two tables, I have a column 'Cases' where its value either could be null or have a number. One table will combine and show all the information where Cases is not null, the other table will combine and show information where Cases is null. Currently have both tables showing rows for both null and not null items. The table where cases are null i am showing values and included are empty rows which are for cases that are not null. How could i remove the empty rows from my tables?

I tried using filter but i guess i am not using it correctly, I tried to show information with a filter expression is `Cases = 0` and tried `Cases = Is Nothing` but i get an error when running it.

How i could control this in my report viewer?

Sample Info:

```
Activity type  hours  activities  cases
Teaching          54          12     23
Preparing         12           9   null
```

In one table it will show Activities with cases:

```
Teaching          54          12     23
```

In the other table it will show Activities with null for cases:

```
Preparing         12           9   null
```

---

What i am getting is an empty row with each table

```
Teaching          54          12     23
-------Empty row------ (this row is for the activity type with null)
```

other table

```
-------Empty row------ (this row is for the activity type with cases)
Preparing         12           9   null
```

I want to be able to remove the empty row from both table where they will show up.

Comment: table structure with some dummy values would be of great help, also your problem seems like more related to sql, add the related tag

Comment: @3nigma - i know that in sql i will be able to eliminate null valued rows but i actually need them. It is in the report viewer where i want to handle the visibility of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to play around with the filters feature and didn't notice there is a selection of text, integer, Boolean.... For my first table, i opened the group properties of the row within the table and under Filters i made the following:

Expression: [Cases]
Operator: >=
Value: 1
Selected from dropdown: Integer

Second Table:

Expression: [Cases]
Operator: <=
Value: 0
Integer